# Grails one to many relationship

Tags: rest, grails, grails-domain-class

In Grails if there is a many to many relation ships for example `book has many authors`

Lets says `book1 has author1,autho2,author3,author4` values .Now a PUT request is sent saying that book1 has only author1,author3 then the other two values are deleted from the table.

Now for the same scenario  with one to many relation ship lets say `book1 has author1,autho2,author3,author4` values now if a PUT request is done with only author1,author3

Is it suppose to delete the other two `i.e, author2 and author4` values?? i expect the behavior to be so..

Below is my model for book and author

```
class Author {
String name;
    static hasMany = [books: Book]

     static mapping = {
    books cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
}
}

class Book{
    String name
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

EDIT:

When i emplement the all-delete-orphan i get the followinh error 
A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the cascade options set. If you are using `belongsTo` on the `Author` table grails uses `cascade all` by default. This means that the `Author` objects are removed if they are not used by any other `Book`. You can customize this behaviour using the [cascade](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html) option (`all-delete-orphan` should be the value you are interested in).

Comment: When i implemented the above suggested, i get an error as A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance.Any sugeestions

Comment: `all-delete-orphan` should be added to the owning side of the relationship. Update your question with the exact modifications you have done. @Hulk